# Magento 2: Ram memory issue

Tags: magento2, server-setup, optimization, memory

I have Magento2 website on production mode. And i have 8gb ubuntu 16.04 server. But i have checked ram memory uses 99% so my website is working slow.

Please any one tell me why used my memory 99%?

Which module take lots of memory in Magento?

Comment: Are you using dadicated server or shared server?

Comment: So have you checked your access logs for unusual traffic, check for the processes spiking RAM?

Comment: I am using dedicated hosting @SaphalJha

Comment: could you please try this command and post results: `free -m` or this command when you have high load: `top | head -n 5`

Comment: @MagenX I have checked mysqld take lots of memory

Comment: then you need either to clean excess data or add more ram, or maybe you have swapping and slow hdd... you dont post much information...

Comment: On my server swapping is 0. Can you tell me swapping is important for ram memory? @MagenX

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner,pl report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: @MasudShaikh Posting the additional information requested May 22, 19 would allow preparation of suggestions to reduce RAM use and improve response time.

Comment: @MasudShaikh Please consider posting the additional information requested May 22, 19 would allow preparation of suggestions to reduce RAM use and improve response time.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to understand your memory allocation and database status.

enable magento profiler:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html

check your data:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --all-databases
```

check your database using mysqltuner script:
https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/blob/master/mysqltuner.pl

login to mysql shell and check tables size:

```
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) ASC;
```

you can also open database in phpMyAdmin and sort tables by size. There are many tables too big? Some tables you can safely truncate. especially logs and debug data.

another option is to see actually what mysql is doing: install `mytop` monitoring tool.
now you see all the threads. are they running too long, red color?

```
MYTOP="http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mytop/mytop_1.9.1.orig.tar.gz"
cd /usr/local/src
wget -qO - ${MYTOP} | tar -xzp && cd mytop*
perl Makefile.PL && make && make install
```

mytop config file `/root/.mytop`:

```
user=root
pass=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}
db=mysql
```

now after you can see the picture. either your mysql `my.cnf`configuration is wrong, and you allocating memory incorrectly, or your database is broken or tables/data corrupted, maybe some bots are heavily drilling your bad custom scripts or code, or you just need to add more ram to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You should check below things with your database:

- Check for the log tables and truncate them
  Optimize Magento Database:  https://magento2x.com/optimize-magento-database-by-cleaning-log/
- Customer session should be set to file not to the database
- Check mysql query execution time and check which query taking long time
- Check with magento profiled to specific section execution time
- if you are using varnish cache then try to switch it to mangento build-in cache and check and compare the performance.
- check for the cron, if it is running in every 5 minute the check the scheduled cron.

May be this will help you, because you will have to figure out the things one by one manually.

Answer (score 0):

You asked,
On my server swapping is 0. Can you tell me swapping is important for ram memory?

Please consider the observations in this url

https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-space/

for the details on WHY you need swap space, rather than failures at critical times and the % of swap space you need relative to RAM size and possibility of HIBERNATION.

Read the content more than once, please.